# Convert VBScript Code to Power Shell Code to write the value on the Active Directory computer account description from the windows 10 workstation

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I'm trying to write the value on the Active Directory computer account description from the windows 10 workstation.
I success to use this VB Script on startup up group policy on all workstations to write some values (Computer hardware specs) on the Active Directory computer account description.

```
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objSysInfo.UserName)
Set objComputer = GetObject("LDAP://" & objSysInfo.ComputerName)
objComputer.Description = "Tested PC"
objComputer.SetInfo
```

is it possible to use `Set-ADComputer -Identity computername -Description "Test"` from windows 10 workstation without install any module or any other tool.

[image]

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `[ADSI]` classes to search AD for the computer object and set attributes:

```
$filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(objectClass=computer)(cn=$env:COMPUTERNAME))"
$computer = [ADSI](([adsisearcher]$filter).FindOne().Path)
$computer.description = $NewDescription
$computer.setinfo()
```